# IsArray in Jade? looping through a collection versus displaying as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Newcomer to Jade.   Simple problem which boils down to deciding whether a variable is an array or not.

My JSON:

```
{
  "firstName" : “tom",
  “pets" : “mouse"
}
{
  "firstName" : “phil",
  “pets" : [“cat", “dog", “horse"]
}
```

So sometimes pets is an array, sometimes not.   When I try this in my template:

```
ul
    each user in requestList
        li= user.firstName
            ul
                each p in pets
                    li= p
```

It's looping through the comma delim array as intended, but when it gets to a single pet it loops through the chars in the array:

```
tom
  m
  o
  u
  s
  e
phil
  cat
  dog
  horse
```

I need the inner each loop to 'decide' whether pets is an array or not.  isArray doesn't work; isArray() throws an error.  I could sniff for a comma, but that seems very clunky considering how slick Jade is  (so far.)

```
ul
    each user in requestList
        li= user.firstName
            ul
                if user.pets.isArray
                    each p in pets
                        li= p
                else
                    li= user.pets
```

This might be a JS question in general, come to think of it, but I'm looking specifically for the Jade syntax.

Answer (score 1):

My inline JavaScript solution, for what it's worth:

```
            - if(user.pets.constructor == Array)
```

It works fine but I'll wait and see for something Jade.

Answer (score 0):

Try with length

```
 ul
       li= user.firstName
            ul
               if user.pets > 1
                  each pet in pets
                      li= pet
                    else
                      li= user.pets
```

Comment: That's what I would have figured too, no luck.  Also tried the Length property. It still splits the string into a char array and lists each letter.  The inline check below works.  Can't say whether it's recommended though.